# Google fit Authorization cancelled in internal test build

Tags: android, react-native, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I have released my app to internal testing with google fit implementation and google fit fails to authorize user in app installed from internal testing. However, it works when same apk file is installed through adb. I have created Oauth credentials and added SHA1 key and Google recently verified the fitness API scopes.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

Needed to add App signing key certificate sha1 key to oAuth credential.

Here is detail explanation: https://github.com/StasDoskalenko/react-native-google-fit/issues/332